# How to pass Json or Jsobject to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, geometry

How to pass Json or JObject result into javascript function

CODES :

I use Postgres Database
Create table :

```
CREATE TABLE "TLandPoint"
(
    gid integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    geom geometry,
    "LandId" bigint NOT NULL,
    "SumSpace" bigint NOT NULL,
    "CityLevelId" bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_TLandPoint" PRIMARY KEY (gid)
        USING INDEX TABLESPACE "MyDB"
)

TABLESPACE "MyDB";

ALTER TABLE "TLandPoint"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

insert sample data

```
INSERT INTO "TLandPoint"(
     geom, "LandId", "SumSpace", "CityLevelId")
    VALUES ( '0101000000F30D15E765D355410C3A0D001F1B5041', 5698, 13500, 123001002);
```

and create view for convert geom to json

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "TLandPointView"
 AS
 SELECT "TLandPoint".gid,
    st_asgeojson("TLandPoint".geom) AS jsonpoint,
    "TLandPoint"."LandId",
    "TLandPoint"."SumSpace",
    "TLandPoint"."CityLevelId"
   FROM "TLandPoint";

ALTER TABLE "TLandPointView"
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Load data from view with Linq

```
var TLandPts =DbContext.TLandPointView.AsQueryable();
```

and use this code to create JObject

```
JObject rss =
        new JObject(
        new JProperty("type", "FeatureCollection"),
        new JProperty("features",
                new JArray(from p in TLandPts select
                new JObject(
                new JProperty("id", p.gid),
                new JProperty("type", "Feature"),
                new JProperty("geometry", new JObject(JObject.Parse(p.jsonpoint))),
                new JProperty("properties",
                    new JObject(
                        new JProperty("LandId", p.LandId),
                        new JProperty("SumSpace", p.SumSpace),
                        new JProperty("CityLevelId", p.CityLevelId)
                        )
                
                    )
                )
                )
            )
        );
            var y = rss.ToString();
```

and use this code to pass y to my function

in controler

```
public IActionResult Index(){
ViewBag.Land = y;
return view()
}
```

in index.cshtml

```
<script>
LoadData('@ViewBag.Land');
</script
```

and into javascript

```
function loadData(mydata){
    var PointSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(mydata)
    });
    var PointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: PointSource
    });
    map.addLayer(PointLayer);

}
```

codes in javascript changed to like this image

[image: changed code]

but when i copy result y variable into javascript for example mydata do not have any problem
[image: code1]

Comment: I use c# and .net core5

Answer (score 0):

Solved Problem

```
string jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rss);
```

and in javascript

```
var MDy = JSON.parse(ArraypolyData.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
```